# Bitwise operators in if statements

Tags: c

I'm unsure of how to set my if statements using bitwise operators, I got it to work using conditonal operators and summing up the enum however I want to know how I should be able to do it with & or |.

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
 #include <stdio.h>
 
typedef enum eUser_Permissions
{
VIEW =1,
ADD=2,
EDIT=4,
DELETE=8
} User_Permissions;

void print_permissions(char* username, int permissions);

int main(void){
int x = VIEW;
int j = VIEW | ADD | EDIT;
int s = VIEW | ADD | EDIT | DELETE;
print_permissions("S", s);
print_permissions("X", x);
print_permissions("J", j);

return 0;
}


 void print_permissions(char* username, int permissions)
{

if (permissions ==15)
{
    printf("%s's permissions (%d): VIEW ADD EDIT DELETE", username, permissions);
    printf("\n");
}
if (permissions ==1)
    {
    printf("%s's permissions (%d): VIEW", username, permissions);
    printf("\n");
    }
if (permissions == 7)
{
    printf("%s's permissions (%d): VIEW ADD EDIT", username, permissions);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `if(permissions & EDIT) printf("You may edit\n");` Notice that the powers of 2 assign one permission per bit, making them easy to combine and test.

Comment: How can I do it for multiple options i.e. can view, edit and add. I used (permissions & VIEW & ADD & EDIT) and it's still showing up as view for someone who can view, add and edit.

Comment: One at a time: `printf("You may"); if(permissions & EDIT) printf(" EDIT"); if(permissions & VIEW) printf(" VIEW");` ... etc. There are 4 permissions, so if you work through all 16 combinations that is more work than dealing with the 4 individual permsissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initially set the permissions using the bitwise OR operator, so just do the same when checking:

```
if (permissions == (VIEW | ADD | EDIT | DELETE))
```

If you want to check each condition individually, use a bitwise AND between the passed in value and the permission in question:

```
printf("%s's permissions (%d):", username, permissions);
if (permissions & VIEW) {
    printf(" VIEW");
}
if (permissions & ADD ) {
    printf(" ADD");
}
if (permissions & EDIT ) {
    printf(" EDIT");
}
if (permissions & DELETE) {
    printf(" DELETE");
}
printf("\n");
```